# Query not returning correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run a query on people who haven't had a specific type of appointment and only this type of appointment, however when I run the query I am still getting tons of results.

I want only people who haven't had this certain appointment in this specific date range. 
Here is my query so far.

```
select COUNT(patient.PatientID)
from Episode
join Patient
on Episode.PatientID = patient.PatientID
where Episode.EpisodeTypeID not in
(
'FCB9EAA0-C814-413E-A5FC-48547EF973B7',
'E422A8FA-839B-44AD-9A60-6973FEF39361',
'9254B31D-A304-498C-ADE4-F4003997C8FA')
and Episode.EpisodeDate between '2016-04-01' and '2016-12-15'
```

As you can see, I only want people who haven't had these specific EpisodeID's, and *only* these ID's.
When I run the query, it just removes these appointments and still shows me every other appointment they have had in this date range.

Comment: The query doesn't ask what you think it does. It asks for *all* patients* and their episodes except episodes with the specific IDs. You haven't placed any restriction on the `Patient` table, so all Patients match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach this using `not exists` or `not in`:

```
select COUNT(p.PatientID)
from patient p
where not exists (select 1
                  from Episode e
                  where e.PatientID = p.PatientID and
                        e.EpisodeTypeID in ('FCB9EAA0-C814-413E-A5FC-48547EF973B7',
                                            'E422A8FA-839B-44AD-9A60-6973FEF39361',
                                            '9254B31D-A304-498C-ADE4-F4003997C8FA'
                                           ) and
                        e.EpisodeDate between '2016-04-01' and '2016-12-15'
                  );
```

Your query is doing something quite different.  It is counting the number of episodes that are not those three.  It is not counting patients at all.

Comment: This has definitely given me better results, however it's still not quite right. I have just run a query and have found that there are a total of 255 patients in this database. When I ran your query it gave me 294 results. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm stupid. Nevermind. Your query worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This Way you get "only people who haven't had this certain appointment in this specific date range".

```
select patient.PatientID from Patient 
except
select patient.PatientID
  from Episode
  join Patient on Episode.PatientID = patient.PatientID
 where Episode.EpisodeDate between '2016-04-01' and '2016-12-15'
   and Episode.EpisodeTypeID in ('FCB9EAA0-C814-413E-A5FC-48547EF973B7','E422A8FA-839B-44AD-9A60-6973FEF39361','9254B31D-A304-498C-ADE4-F4003997C8FA')
```